# In an R Package, How do You Force Load Packages That Are Imports

Tags: r

My DESCRIPTION file requires a handful of packages (I've shown two below for simplicity):

```
Imports:
    tidyverse,
    magrittr
```

In my NAMESPACE file, I then use export(functions) for functions I WRITE, and I used `import(tidyverse)`, `import(magrittr)` so ALL functions in these packages get loaded automatically. However, this isn't working and I still have to call `library(tidyverse)` after I load my package.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want these other packages to load so that loading your package also loads them, you need to put them in `depends`, not `imports`

Comment: Putting them in depends has not caused them to be auto-loaded (for myself, or friends who are testing my package.) They still have to be loaded manually.

Comment: Are you putting in the exact line `Depends: magrittr` in your DESCRIPTION file?

Comment: Thanks again for your quick reply. I'm having some trouble getting the formatting for comments on StackOverflow down, but yes, I have the Depends section (after the other mandatary DESCRIPTION fields) and then I have all the plugins I want to be installed right below.

Comment: Just wanted to update, this was an issue with the updates to my code not properly being pushed to Github. So when I would install my package with depends from Github, it wasn't adding this change. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it seems like {tidyverse} is [not suggested to be imported directly](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2018/06/tidyverse-not-for-packages/) (more info: [Including tidyverse packages in another package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44992890/including-tidyverse-packages-in-another-package)). As far as I understand your question, the reason I found this question in the first place is: How do I load the imported packages in my environment? I was doing some testing and I needed them fast, i.e. w/o loading manually all the imports (incidentally `setup.R` in {testthat} should NOT have those library calls in imports). The solution to this is to do load all:

```
devtools::load_all()
```